# OLEDB error "Cannot find column no"

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb

I am getting data from an EXCEL sheet using OLEDB connection. But it is reading BLANK column too. Let say I have 4 column TITLE, FNAME, LNAME AND ADDRESS.

While reading data it is also reading data from next columns i.e all 255 columns .
MY requirement is to read data from A,B,C,D column not  other columns of the row.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: _How_ are you getting data?  `SELECT *`?  Are you specifying column names?

Comment: Except specifying all column name is there any way to achieve this task.

Comment: This question lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.  Please include the [relevant parts of the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain what you're trying to accomplish and how your results differ from the desired results. Include any error messages you receive. Please read this advice on [ask] and Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Comment: using (OleDbConnection objConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionSting))
                        {
                            string query = "SELECT * FROM [" + lstSheetNames[0] + "]";
                            using (OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, objConnection))
                            {
                                objAdapter.Fill(dtLeadInfo);
                            }
                        }

Comment: Above is my code. Is there any way to select first 4 column from the sheet. Let say i will fetch only A TO D column data .

Answer (score 1):

> Except specifying all column name is there any way to read data from A,B,C,D column not other columns of the row

Not reliably.  If there's any indication of data in other columns (even data that has been deleted) OleDB will try to pull them.

You could *try* adding `;IMEX=1` to your connection string, but that may turn some columns into text that you don;t expect.

The safest way is to specify the columns:

```
SELECT 
    TITLE, FNAME, LNAME, ADDRESS
FROM Sheet1$
```

Comment: I have around 45 columns and this no changes time to time :(